# Auto calibration of internal RTC

Tags: embedded, stm32, calibration, stm32f4discovery

In my Application I want to make a kind of auto-calibration of the internal RTC. I want avoid (if possible) to use external equipment for the calibration. My idea is to use the Smooth calibration with 32 second calibration window. I want to check the correct 32 second using an internal timer (clocked by Sytem Clock). There is someone with success in this ?

Comment: I thought the calibration uses a 50Hz signal from AC.

Comment: I'm working an application that can be used in different parts of the world... in a lot of case the 50Hz support is efficient but in other case the 50Hz is not precise and this can be a problem. This is why I want avoid the external equipment or external reference.

Comment: Is internal RTC clocked by an external 32 KHz quarz? What is your platform?

Comment: External quarts is 32768. My STM32F429 run with quartz at 8MHz

Comment: How you think to compensate the 8MHz jitter, temperature derating and use it to calibrate the RTC? I never tried, but smell like a dirty way..

Comment: Yes I know... but I can find a 8MHz quarz with a low ppm of error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking with Application Field Engineering of ST, normally the suggested oscillator with suggested capacitors should be used in the board design. With the suggested components the RTC should be very precise.
Is possible to create an auto-calibration using the main clock but only if this is generated from a very high precision oscillator.